# Creates a maze from file and enable user to go trough it with graphic display

Tags: python, beginner, game, python-2.x, pygame

I'm following the learnpythonthehardway.org book for learning Python. I recently made a one week projet and as I'm fairly new to coding program with POO and multiple files, I'd like to have someone else's opinion on my code (regarding structure, coding style, etc.).

The project is a little maze game where the player have to reach the end by surviving the obstacle and "monster" he encounter.

"maze.py" contains the maze(2d list) and the methods to move the player trough it. It also contains rooms classes, their behaviors and the player class.

maze.py

```
from random import choice  # Used for random choice of the foe.

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from display import Display


class Room(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.display = Display()

class Start(Room):

    def enter(self, player):
        self.display.display_text_output("You've come back to the start.")
        return False

class Empty(Room):

    def enter(self, player):
        self.display.display_text_output("You walk on the grass.")
        return False

class Foe(Room):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foe, self).__init__()

        foes_list = [
            {'name': "Evil Mushroom", 'place': "hidden at the foot of a bush.",
             'strength': 3, 'action': "call is friends and they punch your feet."},
            {'name': "Grass Goblin", 'place': "lying on the ground.",
             'strength': 4, 'action': "stands, jumps on you and bites your arm."},
            {'name': "Warrior Tree", 'place': "standing in the middle of the path.",
             'strength': 6, 'action': "smashes you with his wooden spear."}
        ]
        self.foe = choice(foes_list)

    def enter(self, player):
        self.display.display_text_output(
            "You encounter a " + self.foe['name'] + "\n"
            "He is " + self.foe['place'] + "\n"
            "He " + self.foe['action'] + "\n"
            "You take " + str(self.foe['strength']) + " damage.\n"
            "The " + self.foe['name'] + " disappaer in the bushes."
        )
        player.life_point -= self.foe['strength']
        self.display.display_window()

        return True

class Trap(Room):

    def enter(self, player):
        self.display.display_text_output(
            "You see a hole in front of you.\n"
            "What do you do?\n"
            "1. Jump over the hole\n"
            "2. Jump onto the hole"
        )
        self.display.display_window()

        loop = True
        while loop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == QUIT:
                    exit()
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_1:
                    self.display.display_text_output("You jump over the hole and "
                                                     "continue your way.")
                    loop = False
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_2:
                    self.display.display_text_output(
                        "You jump in the hole and you hurt you.\n" +
                        "You take 5 damage.\n" +
                        "You manage to rise to the surface and you continue your way."
                    )
                    player.life_point -= 5
                    loop = False
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exit()

        return False

class Health(Room):

    def enter(self, player):
        """When the player will enter this room, it will recover some life points."""
        health = 3

        self.display.display_text_output("You find some berries and you eat them.\n" +
                                         "You recover " + str(health) + " life points.")
        player.life_point += health
        self.display.display_window()

        return True

class End(Room):

    def enter(self, player):
        self.display.display_end()
        exit()


class Player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.life_point = 10
        self.position_x = 0
        self.position_y = 0
        self.picture = pygame.image.load("images/player.png").convert()
        self.picture.set_colorkey((255,255,255))


class Maze(object):

    rooms = {
        'start': Start(),
        'empty': Empty(),
        'foe': Foe(),
        'trap': Trap(),
        'health': Health(),
        'end': End()
    }

    def __init__(self, player):
        self.maze = []

        with open('maze.csv') as file:
            for line in file:
                line = line.replace('\n', '')
                self.maze.append(line.split(','))

        self.player = player

    def find_in_maze(self, room):
        """Search for all occurrences of "room" in the maze (2d list) and return coordinates"""
        position = [(index, row.index(room)) for index, row in enumerate(self.maze) if room in row]
        return position

    def position_ok(self, x, y):
        """Check if the player can be on a given position in the maze."""
        ok = False

        position_out_of_maze = x > len(self.maze) - 1 or x < 0 or y > len(self.maze[x]) - 1 or y < 0

        # We check if the given x and y coordinate don't exceed the size of the maze.
        if position_out_of_maze:
            ok = False
        else:
            # Then we check if there is not a wall at the given position.
            if self.maze[x][y] == 'wall':
                ok = False
            else:
                ok = True

        return ok

    def move_player(self, direction):
        """Change the position of the player in the maze depending of a given direction.

        :param direction: text which indicate in which direction the player will move.
        """
        player_pos_x = self.player.position_x
        player_pos_y = self.player.position_y
        previous_position = [self.player.position_x, self.player.position_y]

        if direction == 'up' and self.position_ok(player_pos_x - 1, player_pos_y):
            self.player.position_x -= 1
        elif direction == 'down' and self.position_ok(player_pos_x + 1, player_pos_y):
            self.player.position_x += 1
        elif direction == 'left' and self.position_ok(player_pos_x, player_pos_y):
            self.player.position_y -= 1
        elif direction == 'right' and self.position_ok(player_pos_x, player_pos_y + 1):
            self.player.position_y += 1

        current_position = [self.player.position_x, self.player.position_y]

        # We don't enter the room again if the position of the player hasn't changed.
        if current_position != previous_position:
            self.enter_room()

    def enter_room(self):
        """Enter the room at the current player position."""
        player_position = self.maze[self.player.position_x][self.player.position_y]
        room = Maze.rooms.get(player_position)
        disappear = room.enter(self.player)

        if disappear:
            # We replace the room with an empty room.
            self.maze[self.player.position_x][self.player.position_y] = 'empty'
```

"display.py" contains all the informations and methods to display the graphical elements of the game and the different screens (title, game, game over, etc.).

display.py

```
from time import sleep  # Used to display the end screen

import pygame
from pygame.locals import * # Import the pygame constant

from external.textrect import render_textrect

class Display(object):

    window = None
    maze = None
    player = None
    information = None

    def display_maze(self):
        """Display the maze on the screen using the tiles.png image."""

        # We start with coordinates set to 10 to shift a bit the maze in the x and y axis.
        x = 10
        y = 10

        tileset = pygame.image.load('images/tiles.png')

        # We create a 32*32 surface and then we move the tileset to display
        # only the tile we need in the 32*32 surface.
        room = pygame.Surface((32, 32))

        for line in Display.maze:
            for column in line:

                if column == 'wall':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (0, 0, 96, 64))
                elif column == 'start':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (64, 0, 96, 64))
                elif column == 'empty':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (32, 0, 96, 64))
                elif column == 'foe':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (32, 32, 96, 64))
                elif column == 'trap':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (64, 32, 96, 64))
                elif column == 'health':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (0, 64, 96, 64))
                elif column == 'end':
                    room.blit(tileset, (0, 0), (0, 32, 96, 64))
                else:
                    # If the element in the list is unknown we just draw a
                    # black square to know that there is something wrong.
                    pygame.draw.rect(Display.window, (0, 0, 0), (x, y, 32, 32), 0)

                Display.window.blit(room, (x, y))

                x += 32
            x = 10
            y += 32

    def display_information(self):
        """Display the player's life points at the bottom right of the screen."""
        # We get the width of the window to have a relative position to blit the text.
        x = Display.window.get_width()

        # We draw a rectangle over the previous text to erase it.
        pygame.draw.rect(Display.window, (181, 230, 29), (x - 65, 275, 50, 100), 0)

        font_health = pygame.font.Font(None, 18)
        health = font_health.render("Health", 1, (21, 108, 48))
        Display.window.blit(health, (x - 60, 290))

        font_lp = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        life_point = font_lp.render(str(Display.player.life_point), 1, (21, 108, 48))
        Display.window.blit(life_point, (x - 52, 310))

    def display_player(self):
        """Blit the player on the screen according to its position in the maze."""
        # We do "position + 10" to place the player correctly on the maze.
        Display.window.blit(Display.player.picture, (Display.player.position_y * 32 + 10,
                                                     Display.player.position_x * 32 + 10))

    def display_text_output(self, text):
        """Display the text automatically formatted in a rectangle."""
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 22)
        rect = pygame.Rect((15, 275, 500, 100))
        text_color = (21, 108, 48)
        rect_color = (181, 230, 29)

        rendered_text = render_textrect("\n" + text, font, rect, text_color, rect_color, 1)

        if rendered_text:
            Display.window.blit(rendered_text, rect.topleft)
        else:
            print "Can't render text."

    def display_title_screen(self):
        title = True
        title_image = pygame.image.load("images/title.png").convert()

        Display.window.blit(title_image, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

        while title:
            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == QUIT:
                    exit()
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RETURN:
                    # Erase the title screen before displaying the games.
                    Display.window.fill((34, 177, 76))
                    title = False
                elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exit()

    def display_gameover(self):
        gameover = pygame.image.load("images/gameover.png").convert()
        Display.window.blit(gameover, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

        sleep(5)

    def display_end(self):
        end = pygame.image.load("images/end.png").convert()
        Display.window.blit(end, (0, 0))
        pygame.display.flip()

        sleep(5)

    def display_window(self):
        """Display the main graphical elements of the game."""
        self.display_maze()
        self.display_player()
        self.display_information()
        pygame.display.flip()
```

You can find the entire project here : https://github.com/Onimanta/ex45_pythonHardway

ps: English is not my native language so be tolerant please :)

Comment: **Try to write a title that summarizes what your code does**, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](https://CodeReview.meta.StackExchange.com/a/2438/41243) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in your code:

```
elif direction == 'left' and self.position_ok(player_pos_x, player_pos_y):
     self.player.position_y -= 1
```

It should actually be `player_pos_y - 1` in the first line.

You can reduce the chances of making such bugs by storing a shift vector for each direction in a dict and using a shift function:

```
shift_vect = {'up': (-1, 0), 'down': (1, 0), 'left': (0, -1), 'right': (0, 1)} 

def shift_by(pos, shift):
    return pos[0] + shift[0], pos[1] + shift[1]
```

After that, the move gets very simple:

```
new_pos = shift(player_pos, shift_vect[direction])
prev_pos = player_pos
if player_position_ok(new_pos):
     player_pos = new_pos
if player_pos != prev_pos:
     # do something here
```

I would also load the `foes_list` in the `Foe` class constructor from a file because it looks like a reasonable thing to make customizable.

There're also a lot of "magic" constants in your code (for instance, (64, 0, 96, 64). What does it mean? I have no clue). You can make your code cleaner by creating a variable with a meaningful name for each such constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer kraskevich. I'll take your advices and try to improve my code.